# How do I convert a 2D list into a set?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So far I've only found this:

```
myList = [[32, 12, 52, 63], [32, 64, 67, 52], [64,64,17,34], [17, 76, 98]]

mySet = set(i for j in mylist for i in j)
```

As far as I can tell, this is working, but I have no idea why it works.
Could somebody please walk me step by step how the "mySet = set(i for j in mylist for i in j)" bit actually works.

Answer (score 6):

You can `map` the `lists` to `sets` and use `set.union`.

```
myList = [[32, 12, 52, 63], [32, 64, 67, 52], [64,64,17,34], [17, 76, 98]]
my_set = set.union(*map(set,myList))
print (my_set)
set([32, 64, 34, 67, 76, 12, 98, 17, 52, 63])
```

Or in a loop, update takes an iterable and is the most efficient:

```
my_set = set() # create set
for sub_l in myList:
    my_set.update(sub_l)  # update set with each sublist content
print(my_set)
set([32, 64, 34, 67, 76, 12, 98, 17, 52, 63])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can break your set comprehension into a for loop to understand it better

```
mySet = set()                   #declares an empty set
for list in myList:             #loops over the items in myList          (for j in myList)
    for item in list:           #loops over the nested lists in myList   (for i in j)
        mySet.add(item)         #adds the item into the declared set     (i)
```

This is the same thing as the comprehension you have above, but broken down into more lines to make it more readable.

Comment: Thank you! I know this is a pretty RTFM question but this helps me a lot.

Comment: don't use list as a variable name

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I used list as a variable name only to show the structure of what was being parsed, to make it more readable. This is code that is meant to make a comprehension readable, not anything that's supposed to be run.

Comment: still not a good idea, especially as an example for someone starting out lst or sub_l etc.. are  just as understandable.